# Customized enumerate list with a graphic does not align properly

Tags: lists, enumerate, alignment

For my math course I want to create a list that enumerates exercises in such a way that the item number is preceded by a graphic indicating the difficulty level. I got this to work by defining new \item commands, eg \itemlowii for an easy question, but unfortunately, the graphics don't align properly. My MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\itemlowii}{\stepcounter{enumii}\item[{\includegraphics[width=0.01\textwidth]{low}} (\theenumii)]}
\begin{document} 
\Large
\begin{enumerate}
 \item Exercise 
\begin{enumerate}
 \itemlowii Subexercise
 \itemlowii Subexercise
 \itemlowii Subexercise
 \itemlowii Subexercise
 \itemlowii Subexercise
 \itemlowii Subexercise
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This produces something like

[image: Output MWE]

The careful eye observes that the graphics belonging to the third, fifth and sixth item do not properly align and I don't have a clue why this is happening. I hope someone can help. I also explored the enumitem package but it doesn't seem to have the functionality I'm looking for...

The battery I'm using to indicate the difficulty level can be found below.

[image: Battery]

Answer (score 1):

By default, the item label of `enumerate` is aligned to right. That means, the `)` in `(a)`, ..., `(f)` are vertically aligned. You can set the item label to align to left, using option `align=right` from `enumitem` package.

I do not have image `low`. Instead, I use `\faBatteryQuarter` from `fontawesome5` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\lowBattery{%
  \scalebox{.4}{\rotatebox{90}{\faBatteryQuarter}}%
}

\begin{document}
\Large
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Exercise 
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\lowBattery\space (\alph*), align=left]
    \item Subexercise
    \item Subexercise
    \item Subexercise
    \item Subexercise
    \item Subexercise
    \item Subexercise
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I needed!